# why have_posts() , the_post() render pages instead of posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi everyone so I got this piece of code to display posts but instead or rendering posts it renders the about us page can anyone help. I'm running WordPress 4.5.3

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
    if(have_posts() ):
        while(have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_title();
            the_content();
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: have you put any other code apart from this in your file ? what is your file name ?

Comment: make sure you selected which page you have selected as post page in general setting menu

Comment: @Mit.agile this is all I have, there is only the basic structure of an html website on the header.php and footer.php

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

```
$args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => 10,
            'offset'           => 0,
            'category'         => '',
            'category_name'    => '',
            'orderby'          => 'date',
            'order'            => 'DESC',
            'include'          => '',
            'exclude'          => '',
            'meta_key'         => '',
            'meta_value'       => '',
            'post_type'        => 'post',
            'post_mime_type'   => '',
            'post_parent'      => '',
            'author'           => '',
            'author_name'      => '',
            'post_status'      => 'publish',
            'suppress_filters' => true 
        );
        query_posts($args);

        if(have_posts()): the_post();
            while(have_posts()): the_post();
            ?> 
            <h4> <?php the_title();?> </h4>

        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```